# Java, how to kill process on object destroy

Tags: jakarta-ee, garbage-collection, destructor, jboss7.x

Suppose I have an object "A" which starts some process in its constructor. I need to invoke a clean-up method once the object is freed (set to null or went out of its life scope).

The problem is that java has no destructors and a so called "finalize" method is not guaranteed to run right after the object is set to null or went out of scope. Only when the GC considers that "its time has come".

Also I can't use a shutdown hook as my code runs on a Java EE server and is not a simple Java SE application which will run and terminate at once. What can be done in such situation?

Comment: If you give an example of what your are trying to achieve then we might be able to help you to come up with a solution or different approach to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not create your own thread in a Java EE container and neither NEVER try to kill them since this is deprecated and will havoc your virtual machine / Java EE container.

Take a look at the CommonJ JSR 237 which allows to create background workers in a Java EE container: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/commonj/commonj.html

You can control the startup and shutdown of a Java EE application using a ServletContextListener: http://www.roseindia.net/servlets/ServletContextListener-example.shtml.

Answer (score 1):

Its just not possible using Java.

finalize is called whenever the GC wants to remove the object, but not, when the program terminates (which should not happen in a Java EE app).

So the only way is to do it on your own. For example you may use an ObjectPool, where all instances of object A are stored in a list (with an additional timestamp if required). When time comes up (for example triggered by a special URL using wget & cron), you simply iterate through this list and destroy each object not needed anymore.

This is only one (really simple) possible way.